# NSData is returning nil for same file at different filepaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, nsdata, nsurl

I stored an audio file of format `.aiff` in two different folders. The `NSData` is returning `nil` for one file path even though both file paths have the audio file. I double checked the file paths.

The path is like this:

```
//url1 file:///Users/VenkataManiteja/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/80B8117E-D2C9-4B42-8A76-9A89A10FB1C1/data/Containers/Data/Application/FD17AD64-EAF9-4578-B50D-0B5BF6F2DEFF/Documents/28Apr15_090827AM.aif
//url2 file:///Users/VenkataManiteja/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/80B8117E-D2C9-4B42-8A76-9A89A10FB1C1/data/Containers/Data/Application/B60CF270-73CA-4BE4-BA75-B2AC3642360D/Documents/28Apr15_090827AM.aif

NSError *err;
data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1]; //this is working fine
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&err];
data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2]; //nsdata is returning nil
```

Can anyone tell me why the `url2` is getting the `nil` `NSData`?

Comment: url2 file may exist but be empty. Check the file size in the Finder.

Comment: no its not empty. I checked the file.

Comment: Your problem is that you used `dataWithContentsOfURL:` instead of `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read a file outside of the running app's sandbox.  While both may exist, presumably you are running the application with ID "FD17AD64-EAF9-4578-B50D-0B5BF6F2DEFF", which is why that URL is working while the other one isn't.

I would recommend watching the WWDC video [A Practical Guide to the App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=710) for more on how the security model works.